# spss.Cursor and Frequency

Tags: python, spss

I am trying to find an alternate/faster method to running the Frequency command on a single variable and writing the number of times the value appears in the dataset to a new variable.  My current setup uses Syntax and writes the output to a new SAV file (oms send), which take several hours to run.

I am looking for some sample code that might show how this can be done with spss.Cursor, where it first reads the variable I want to get the Frequency on, saved it to a list by the number of times each value occurs, then writes the value to a new variable within the current dataset.

I understand how the read and write cursors work, but am having an issue how to count the number of times the variable occurs/stores it in a list, which is then written to the new variable.  I have read through the Spss/python plugin manual, and haven't been able to recognize the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered the `AGGREGATE` command with `MODE = ADDVARIABLES`? For example:

```
AGGREGATE OUTFILE = * MODE = ADDVARIABLES
 /BREAK = var1
 /var1_n = n.
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was not aware of this command, and this has saved me hours of computation time!